# Advance Approval according to § 81a AufenthG & Blue Card for work permit in Germany

Tags: germany, working-visas, resident-permit, blue-card, skilled-migration

If the salary of a future employee (also happens to be a skilled worker) in Germany already qualifies for Blue Card, can the employee still get Advance Approval according to § 81a AufenthG for fast-track procedure, or is this procedure valid only for those employees (also happen to be skilled workers) whose salary is less than what qualifies for Blue Card?

Although I couldn't find this in official documentation, through communication with many people online, there is this confusion that fast-track procedure is for only those skilled workers whose salary, as of when they apply for visa, is less than what qualifies for Blue Card.

More information about the fast-track procedure can be found [here](https://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/looking-for-foreign-professionals/targeted-recruitment/entering-working-in-germany/the-fast-track-procedure-for-skilled-workers/) and [here](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/skilled-worker-immigration/2304796?openAccordionId=item-2304826-14-panel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence of § 81a AufenthG reads

> Arbeitgeber können bei der zuständigen Ausländerbehörde in Vollmacht des Ausländers, der zu einem Aufenthaltszweck nach den §§ 16a, 16d, 18a, 18b und 18c Absatz 3 einreisen will, ein beschleunigtes Fachkräfteverfahren beantragen.

The EU Blue card is controlled by § 18b so it is covered by the fast-track procedure (you will find a lot of confusing references, e.g. to § 19a all over the web as the articles of the law were renumbered a few months ago).

Comment: So all in all, even if the salary qualifies for Blue Card, the fast-track procedure can still be followed: which means the embassy will give an appointment within 3 weeks, right?

Comment: @ArslanAli The rule is three weeks of getting the approval of the local “foreigners authority”. I don't know if all embassies are able to meet this target at the moment. This presumes of course that you do qualify, your application was complete and it was submitted to the right authority by your employer.

Comment: In general Germany is very fastidious with the recognition of foreign qualifications, degrees are a big deal over there. That step is likely to be the longest. The relevant institution has two months to respond but again, this presumes that the application was complete and they don't need additional information.

Comment: You are right. Back in March, the German embassy in Pakistan was offering appointments even the very next day for fast-track procedures, so it's all good. Thanks a lot.